# htmlunit artifact not found with maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit

I have the following pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org    /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.aaaa</groupId>
  <artifactId>david1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.37.1</version>
    </dependency> 
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I get an error:
Missing artifact net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.13

What could be the reason?

From the effective pom i get

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

I did try to google the error but did not find anything.

Best regards,

David

Comment: This looks like a transitive dependency failure. Have you tried Googling the error message? Are you using a corporate Maven repository, or just the standard one?

Comment: I did try to google the results but it did not help. this i get from the effective pom  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

Comment: You can find the necessary jar in the Sonatype OSS repository: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like some of the transitive dependencies of `selenium-java` cannot be resolved.

Suspicious thing is that `2.37.1` version is not listed in [MVNRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java).

It might be that it is not yet released. Try more stable version, like `2.35.0`

Comment: Hi,Using 2.35 worked. There is maybe a typo in the maven website where they write to use the version 2.37.1 http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp